# Can't open csv file in PyCharm File not found

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to open a csv file in PyCharm with Pandas, but I get an error message that the csv file is not found? Does it matter where the file is being placed? I tried to open it also with the full path to the file, but it did not work.
[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ly8Y.png)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("c:\users\user\desktop\jeopardy.csv")
print(df.head())
```

Comment: Yes, it does matter where the file is placed. Please show the code where you tried the full path but it didn't work for you. And don't attach it as an image, paste the actual code and error into your question.

Comment: Could you show me the file directories as I cannot help if I don't know where the files are stored.

Comment: import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("c:\users\user\desktop\jeopardy.csv")
print(df.head())

Comment: I could not edit my question properly so that you can see the code, I do apologize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file path in the screenshot suggests, that the CSV-file is in the same directory as the `.py`-file you are executing to import it. If this is not the case, it will throw the error displayed on your screenshot.

Thus, look for the path to the CSV-file and append it as a string in front of the current file name (don't forget to exchange the backslashes `\` for slashes `/` when copying the path to Python).

If this does not work, double-check the name of the file and if it is an actual CSV-file.

Comment: Thank you, your answer really helped me. I am quite new and I am strugelling with such an easy problems, I hope I will get better.

Comment: Sure, no problem, that's what the community is there for!

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the `\` characters in the path name:

```
df = pd.read_csv("c:\\users\\user\\desktop\\jeopardy.csv")
```

or use a raw-string by putting `r` before the string:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"c:\users\user\desktop\jeopardy.csv")
```